# In Flutter, is there any way to open a url in a specific browser (installed, but not necessarily default)?

Tags: flutter

I'm only targeting Android and iOS for now and the url_launcher plugin only works for default browser.

Comment: hope this helps `https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-open-url-examples` @AchalYash

Comment: The problem is, you can either open the links in the default browser or within the app. What I wanted to do is, for instance, if the default browser in chrome I should be able to either open it in Firefox directly or at least get the options tray to choose a browser. @MorbiusBlack